# Sum() Window Function in PySpark without defining window spec

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, palantir-foundry, spark-window-function

I am trying to add a new column "grand total" to my table on each row.

E.G:

| first_name | Order_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2.5 |
| Ali | 2 | 2 |
| Abdul | 3 | 3.5 |

What I want is:

| first_name | Order_id | price | grand_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 2.5 | 8 |
| Ali | 2 | 2 | 8 |
| Abdul | 3 | 3.5 | 8 |

**My code:**

```
new_df = new_df.withColumn("grand_total",F.sum(F.col("price")).over())
```

The **error** I receive is :

** TypeError: over() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'" **

I am confused because, I am coming from SQL background, and **SUM(column_name) over ()** is possible without the need to define a window inside **over ()**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
new_df = new_df.withColumn("grand_total",F.sum(F.col("price")).over(Window.partitionBy()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by aggregating the column price using a sum function and then create a column called grand_total, passing the value of sum to it. Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, col, lit
total_sum_price = new_df.agg(sum(col('price')).collect()[0][0]
new_df = new_df.withColumn('grand_total',lit(total_sum_price))
```

Comment: Appreciate this workaround, however, I am looking to make the code snippet work OR at least understanding why this works in SQL and not in PySpark

Comment: Well, using over() requires a Window element in pyspark... it is a requirement. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.over.html?highlight=over#pyspark.sql.Column.over